# understanding RMS function in Matlab

Tags: matlab

i am using the Rms function of Matlab to calculate the Rms value of acclerometer samples and then plotting it on maps.i do not understand the DIM variable in rms function

> Y = rms(X,DIM);

what is the use of it ?does it specify the no of samples of which Rms value will be calculated?please help
EDIT:`col1 = Array(:,1);rmsval=rms(col1,2);` i used in this way but when i check the `col1` and `rmsval`  value and even plot them they both are same. doesn't it should be different?

Comment: MathWorks wrote their very own [documentation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/rms.html) for MATLAB recently

Comment: i read the document but couldn't co relate with what i was doing so asked here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Matlab's help:

> rms(X,DIM) operates along the dimension DIM

Much like `mean()` or `sum()`, you can calculate `rms()` along rows or columns of a matrix by specifying DIM.

Comment: *rows (1st dimension, `DIM=1`), columns (2nd dimension, `DIM=2`), or any other dimension of a higher dimensional matrix. For ref: [Docs](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/rms.html)

Comment: `col1 = Array(:,1);rmsval=rms(col1,2);` i used in this way but when i check the `col1` and `rmsval`  value and even plot them they both are same. doesn't it should be different?

Comment: That's because you're doing the root mean squared values of a 1D vector across the single column, which is the same as squaring and square rooting every element. You want `rms(col1,1)` to get one RMS value across the rows

Comment: @Wolfie is right. I might add that `rmsval` is not exactly the same as `col1`, but it is its absolute value (since you are basically squaring and then taking the square root of each value).

Comment: @Wolfie @zep so how should i proceed if i want to do the RMS of 10 samples ,then next 10 samples and store it.`col1` contains `18585` samples.

Comment: What have you tried? You could do a simple loop, or if your matrix actually had a multiple of 10 elements you could use `reshape` then `rms` without looping. If you're stuck post another question, but showing what you tried will be expected

Comment: Yes @pranjalkhanduri, please post another question with an example and pleaso also consider selecting this answer if you feel it answered your original question.